# CSS Rectangle As links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 rectangles that I've created with CSS. I want them to be clickable and link them to a file called "index.html". I've been searching over the web but could not find a  way to do it. Is there also a way where hovering your mouse over the rectangle would just have the index.html file pop up but not open in a completely new window? Here is a snippet of what I have so far:

```
.rec
{
    height: 100px;
    width:  125px;
}
#d1
{
    background : lightgreen;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 0%;
}
#r1
{
    background : red;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 10%; position: relative;
}
#r3
{
    background : white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
    left: 20%;  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should see JavaScript and jQuery tutorials. It's what, mostly, makes web pages interactive. Although in here, the best solution is clearly to use

```
<a href="index.html">
```

it would be good for you to learn them, and their incredible power. Check this fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qjntjyyr/

As you can see, it's quite simple. In the next fiddle, I'm using an event for when the mouse goes over the squares.
http://jsfiddle.net/qjntjyyr/1/

Have fun with it, you can manipulate almost everything you want.

Answer (score 0):

The clickable rectangles:

```
<a href="index.html" class="rec" id="r1">Index</a>
<a href="index.html" class="rec" id="r2">Index</a>
<a href="index.html" class="rec" id="r3">Index</a>
```

As for the little box that appears when you hover them, you could use a title="" in the anchor tag, but that has the default styling the OS gives it. To customize one yourself you'd need JavaScript.

Comment: You don't really need JavaScript for the title, you could well use CSS with pseudoelements for it.

Comment: You're right. However if you want really fancy styling, JavaScript is the way to go because CSS alone is limited in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I found an interesting link to learn for your problem:[css-trick](https://css-tricks.com/links-inside-of-larger-clickable-areas/)
But the first answer is a good one to use.